# .NET Core 2.0: Only 'http' and 'https' schemes are allowed. Parameter name: requestUri

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, firebase-cloud-messaging

sI have a Web API built using ASP.NET Core 2.0. I am trying to make a call to Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP v1 to send a push notification to the mobile client. As per documentation, you need to make a call to this endpoint:

> POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send

When I try making this call (with my token) I get an error message about only http and https being allowed:

> Only 'http' and 'https' schemes are allowed. 
>   Parameter name: requestUri

This error message makes me think HttpClient has a problem with the :send part of the Uri. Here is the code I wrote to do this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project-id/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var jsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
var stringConent = new StringContent(jsonMessage, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var fcmCall = await client.PostAsync("messages:send", stringConent);
```

What could I try to solve this issue? Many thanks.

Link to FCM: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

Comment: Correctly because ":" must be escaped (I don't know Firebase but I'm surprised they require you to do that...are you sure?)

Answer (score 1):

You should encode the colon (`:`) in the request URI. You can use the [`WebUtility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility?view=netcore-2.0) class for it:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode("messages:send")
```